# Separated item asp.net dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

My asp.net dropdownlist gets filled from a database. After that an extra-item is attached to the list.

```
Dropdownlist1.DataSource = db.Semester.OrderByDescending(s => s.StartDate);
Dropdownlist1.DataBind();

var currentSemester = db.Project.
    Where(s => s.StartDate < DateTime.Now)
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.StartDate)
    .First().Id;

Dropdownlist1.SelectedValue = currentSemester.ToString();
Dropdownlist1.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("All", "0"));
```

Now how can I display this extra item separated from the others from the database? I tried to add another item and disable it, but it doesn't look nice. I want it to look like the bootstrap separation.

What it looks now:

[image]

Bootstrap separated item:

[image]

Comment: Why not add another one with `Text="______"` or something similar.

Comment: Because when you hover over it, it looks like you can klick it (blue background, white font).

Comment: That's true... But I suspect that the bootstrap dropdown is not a "real" dropdown but a div pretending to be one.

Comment: You could change the CSS of the dropdownlist: go for the :hover state of the list elements which are disabled (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp) and override background-color/cursor/whatever properties are changed on hover.